# How to Marshal Collection of different types

Tags: jaxb

we know that @XmlElementWrapper is used to marshal collection of same type.
Example xml-

As you see Child2 is list of Attr. But my requirment is inside child2 tag,I also need to add tag for count of Attr list like below.

Comment: I don't see any XML or other code, please add it into your question.

Comment: Requirment: <list><fruitlistcount>2</fruitlistcount><fruit><name>Mango</name></fruit><fruit><name>Papaya</name></fruit></list>

Comment: fruitlist count will display number of fruit object inside list.I am completey stuck with this.If somebody could help it wold be great help.I cant use @XmlElementWrapper becuase using it I cant achieve fruitlistcount tag becuase this annotation can have only one type of collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "collection")
@XmlElement(name = "field")
private List<Object> list;
```

You can put anything in Object/class list.

Comment: Please check my previous comment